# Why is it that after doing a full shutdown of my computer, I can turn it back on by hitting any key on my keyboard?

Tags: windows-7

So I have an E-machine computer a friend gave me after having to replace everything in it except the PSU, and it was running clean for quite a while. But then it started locking up to the point I had to unplug it to turn it off, and I could leave unplugged for days, then plug it back in and blindly hit any key on my keyboard and fully power the system up after plugging it back in.

Comment: wow never encountered this!

Comment: When you say *`it started locking up to the point I had to unplug it to turn it off`*, do you mean 1) It wouldn't respond to the power button on the computer case, 2) It wouldn't respond to Windows shutdown, 3) Both, 4) Something else.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature supported by some BIOS types called *wake on keyboard*, it allows keyboard input to be read while the computer power is off. Not all computers and keyboards support this.

In my case, there are specific buttons on the keyboard for *sleep - wake up* and *shutdown - power up*, but I don't think there is any reason a keyboard/computer couldn't be made to work that way on pressing "any" key.

Are you sure it didn't power-up on keyboard activity before (after being plugged in)?  I mean, you probably didn't unplug and plug-in the computer before, on a frequent basis. It could be that upon being plugged in it has always been able to be powered up by pressing a key on the keyboard, but that situation has never presented itself before. You might have had occasion to press a key after shutting the computer down and that may not have powered up the computer before. But pressing a key after plugging in and pressing a key after shutdown could be very different situations.